# Retornar exception Java para o Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, exceção

tudo bem?

Estou trabalhando em um projeto, e o *back-end (java)*, está totalmente separado do *front-end*, e eles se comunicam por *REST*.

Estou com uma grande dúvida na questão das exceptions. Por exemplo, ocorreu um erro, no java, SQLException, e queria lançar o retorno dela no ajax. Para exibi-lá em um alert ou modal para o usuario.

Tenho os seguintes códigos:

**Java:**

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response adicionar(Produto produto) throws SQLException
{
    return Response.ok().entity(ProdutoService.insert(produto)).build();
}


Public Produto insert(produto){
    try{
        //tenta inserir dados no banco e retorna produto inserido
    }catch(SQLException e){
        // aqui está o meu 'problema'. Como lançar a exception para o ajax?
    }
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlProduto,
    data: dataJson,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
         //seu produto foi inserido com sucesso 
    }, 
    complete: function(){
         //atualiza a grid com os dados do produto
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //o que devo fazer aqui???
         //como posso exibir para o usuário 
         //um alert ou mensagem conforme o erro ocorrido 
         //na SQLException do java?
    }
});
```

Comment: porque retornar o Stacktrace para o Ajax? É só ali no catch vc enviar uma mensagem de erro pra sua pagina, e fazer um Parse dela no ajax. Vc está usando algum tipo de framework? Struts, Spring mvc? qual?

Comment: @IghorAugusto não estou usando nenhum framework, e assim, o gerente nem está pensando em framework nenhum no momento. E a ideia é essa mesmo, não é necessário trazer o Stacktrace completo para o ajax, e apenas uma mensagem, mas o interessante é que essa mensagem se origine do Java, por exemplo eu poderia retornar o e.getMessage() da exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erico,

Lance normalmente a `SQLException` e no `error:` coloque o seguinte:

```
error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + jqXHR.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

Isto deve exibir o erro detalhado enviado pelo servidor.

Apesar de ser em .Net, tu pode verificar neste link para maiores informações:

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/

Comment: Obrigado @AlexandreStrevenski, acredito que isso será útil em meu projeto, vlw

Comment: Eu usaria `JSON.parse` em vez do `eval`.

Comment: É verdade @bfavaretto, eu copiei o exemplo do link de referência (citado na resposta), mas concordo contigo, JSON.parse seria melhor. Existe uma discussão a respeito: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843343/json-parse-vs-eval

Comment: Beleza, vou fazer isso hoje e vou usar o JSON.parse. @Alexandre, vlw pelo exemplo mesmo em asp.net, pois em casa gosto de usar a tecnologia para me aperfeiçoar. Como no trabalho estou trabalhando bastante com REST, pela primeira vez, junto com Java, em casa estou criando um projeto particular em WebApi com asp.net para aprender e praticar.